# Pytest results JUnit-style xml file test case counting

Tags: python, junit, pytest, bazel

The source base consists of several Python libraries/modules, separated from one another. For each of them, there exists a set of tests, i.e.:

- module called: `foo`, with several files,
- corresponding test file `test_foo.py`, with two tests written using Pytest.

Upon running the tests, I do get an XML file generated with contents similar to these:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<testsuites>
  <testsuite name="foo/test_foo" tests="1" failures="0" errors="0">
    <testcase name="foo/test_foo" status="run" duration="9" time="9"></testcase>
    <system-out><![CDATA[============================= test session starts ==============================
platform linux -- Python 3.6.6, pytest-3.10.1, py-1.7.0, pluggy-0.8.0 -- /usr/bin/python3
cachedir: .pytest_cache
rootdir: ..., inifile: pytest.ini
plugins: timeout-1.3.2, mock-1.10.0, cov-2.6.0
timeout: 60.0s
timeout method: thread
timeout func_only: False
collecting ... collected 2 items

::test_foo_test1
-------------------------------- live log setup --------------------------------
# ... some logging performed in the test...
PASSED                                                                   [ 50%]
::test_foo_test2
-------------------------------- live log call ---------------------------------
# ... some logging performed in the test...
PASSED                                                                   [100%]

=========================== 2 passed in 6.63 seconds ===========================]]></system-out>
  </testsuite>
</testsuites>
```

(**note**: the unaligned part is encapsulated by `system-out` markers)

My `pytest.ini` file is rather simple, and contains just information about logging (`log_cli*`, `log_file*`) and `timeout`. I'm using bazel as the build system, which defines `py_test` jobs, and my assumption is that it somehow adds a default output setting implicitly. This should, however, work similarly even when ran directly.

Now, I'd like to process a bunch of these XML files and extract the total count of tests run, errors, etc. The problem shown by the example, is that the XML file claims the tests count to be `tests="1"`, whereas the stdout from the log shows that at least two items were collected.

It seems to me, that the format counts entire *files* as *test cases*, rather than actual *test cases* colled in the files.

**Is there any easy way in Python to make the testsuite contain the count of `collected items`?**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Are you using the --junitxml=something.xml flag?
https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/usage.html#creating-junitxml-format-files

When I use the --junitxml flag and the produced output includes the correct number of tests.
My guess is that bazel is the one generating the xml output, not pytest, and that it's treating your entire run of pytest as one test.

I think this probably needs to be a bazel tagged question as it's really "how do I have bazel read extra xml files?", and then use --junitxml to generate your own xml.

One more thing. If your xml files get huge with all the captured output, I recommend doing the following:

1. Run with -s to not capture output
2. If you need the session log, run the entire thing as "pytest -s --junitxml=out.xml [other flags, test dirs, files, etc] > out.txt"

You'll then need to archive the out.txt as well, but it keeps the xml from being huge.

Comment: Spot on, likely bazel `py_test` is to blame: https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/issues/3413 (bazel seems treat entire pytest as one test, just as you write). Unfortunate, but can be worked around, i.e. with explicit `--junitxml` of my own :) Thanks!

Comment: FTR, the link is broken. For some reason the `usage.html` page now became much shorter, in particular there's no paragraph about junit.